# Поиск по таблице Yii

Tags: yii

Помогите с поиском по таблице.
Во-первых есть у меня checkBoxList:

```
$form->checkBoxList($model, 'rooms', array(
    '1' => '1',
    '2' => '2',
    '3' => '3',
    '4' => '4',
    '>5' => '>5'
)
```

Так вот, при поиске срабатывает всё, кроме >5. Ломаю голову уже неделю, не могу понять почему.

Далее необходимо сделать поиск по цене "от" и "до", причем, что бы была возможность оставить одно из полей пустым. Делал так, создал в модели 2 переменные:

```
public $min_price;
public $max_price;
```

поиск пробовал делать так:

```
if (isset($this->min_price)){
    $criteria->condition = 'price > :min_price';
    $criteria->params = array(':min_price' => $this->min_price);
}
if (isset($this->max_price)){
    $criteria->condition = 'price < :max_price';
    $criteria->params = array(':max_price' => $this->max_price);
}
```

Поиск корректно не работает. Как сделать чтоб работало?

С чекбоксам частично решил проблему, но такое решение мне не нравиться

> if(in_array(5,$this->rooms)) {
> $criteria->compare('rooms', '> 4');  }
> else  $criteria->compare('rooms',
> $this->rooms);

Так хотя бы начал выводить результаты больше 4х, но если выбрать к примеру 1, 3, 5 всёравно будут выводиться больше 4х, а 1 и 3 не будут, если не выбирать 5, то выводиться всё нормально. Почему если в textField написать >4 то выводятся результаты >4, а если такое значение задать чекбоксу, то не работает?

Comment: > Как сделать чтоб работало?

При наличии одновременно `min_price` и `max_price` в `$criteria->condition` первого не окажется.

Comment: if(!empty($this->min_price)){
            $criteria->compare('price','>='.(int)$this->min_price);
            }       

       if(!empty($this->max_price)){
            $criteria->compare('price','<='.(int)$this->max_price);
            }
Вот так сделал, вроде корректно работает. Как быть с чекбоксами?
Еще, как сравнить 2 поля одной таблицы?
пытаюсь придумать как заставить работать это
        if(($this->lf==1)) {
           $criteria->compare ('floor','floor_total');            
        }

Comment: Для сравнения двух полей в модели в rules достаточно воспользоваться валидатором [compare] (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCompareValidator)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте:

```
if(isset($this->min_price)){
    $criteria->addCondition(new CDbExpression('price >= :min_price'));
    $criteria->params [':min_price'] = $this->min_price;
}
if(isset($this->max_price)){
    $criteria->addCondition = new CDbExpression('price < :max_price'));
    $criteria->params[':max_price'] = $this->max_price;
}
```